# regular expression to match all zeros, length from 1-6

Tags: regex

I am trying to check if a number is composed of all zeros, the number can be from 1-6 digits, it just can't be all zeros.  I came up with this, but this only works if the length is 6. how can I make it so it checks lengths from 1-6?

```
 (?<!\d)(?!000000)\d{6}(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the number can be from 1-6 digits, it just can't be all zeros.

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?!0+$)\d{1,6}$
```

- `(?!0+$)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if input has all zeroes.
- `^\d{1,6}#` will match 1 to 6 digits in input